# Get all text from child nodes with min length

Tags: html, xpath

I have html:

```
<div>
 <div>text test <span>text aa bb</span></div>
 <p>text esa sssddf safdf <a href="">adsfdsf</a> sdf sdf</p>
 <p>text <a href="">adsfdsf</a> sdf
     <b>text esa sssddf safdf <a href="">adsfdsf</a> sdf sdf</b>
 </p>
</div>
```

No I need to have xpath to get all text from div and p elements which has minimum 20 characters length. Is this possible?

For now I tried `//p/text()[string-length() > 20]` but this doesn't work correctly

Expected result:

```
text test text aa bb
text esa sssddf safdf adsfdsf sdf sdf
text adsfdsf sdf text esa sssddf safdf adsfdsf sdf sdf
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xpath deepest node whose string content is longer than a given length](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493323/xpath-deepest-node-whose-string-content-is-longer-than-a-given-length)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that for example `<div>text test <span>text aa bb</span></div>` has two text nodes, `text test` and `text aa  bb`. With your current query, a single text node must be longer than 20 characters.

Determine the length for the string value of each element instead:

```
(//div|//p)[string-length(.) > 20]
```

This will return a set of nodes that fit the predicate, together with their elements. With **XPath 1.0**, there is no chance to join each of them to single string results per result element. Still, you might be able to do this postprocessing outside XPath in the language you're using.

With **XPath 2.0**, you would be able to do following:

```
(//div|//p)[string-length(.) > 20]/data()
```

and receive an output like you're looking for.